# Passing two values for ajaxForm(), using jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I want to pass both the values using ajaxForm, displaying both the values separately in test.php

```
-------test.php-----------------------------------------

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$('#test_form').ajaxForm({
    target:'#result',

    success:function() {
        $('#result').show();
    }
});


</script>



<form id="test_form" method="" action="test1.php">
<input type="submit" id="sub" value="sub_value">
</form>

<div id="result"></div>

-------test1.php---------------------------------------


<?
$t="test value";
$u="test value 1";

?>
```

Thanks
Jean

Comment: you want to pass values $t and $u  from "test1.php" to the success method of ajaxForm?

Answer (score 0):

Hy **Jean**

**Welcome to Stackoverflow**

Here is the fixed code:

```
-------test.php-----------------------------------------

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$.post("test.php", {testval: val}, function(data){
   if (data.length>0){ 
 $('#result').show();
     $("#result").html(data); 
   } 
  }) 


</script>



<form id="test_form" method="" action="test1.php">
<input type="submit" id="sub" value="sub_value" name="testval">
</form>

<div id="result"></div>

-------test1.php---------------------------------------


<?
// now coding in PHP is easiyer
if(isset($POST["testval"]))
{
// this is now for your Learning purposes that you see how things are 
$testval = strip_tags(mysql_escape_string($POST["testval"]));
echo $testval;
}
// thats it have fun :-)
?>
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks....

When I hit the submit button on http://localhost/test.php, it just transfers me to http://localhost/test1.php?testval=sub_value, with a blank page.

I guess I am doing something wrong...

Jean